# tsconfig.json compilerOptions paths don't resolve

Tags: typescript, alias, tsconfig, esbuild

I am writing some code in typescript with the following `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "target": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "@utils": [
        "utils/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

And the following directory tree:

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── preload.js
│   └── renderer.js
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   └── index.ts
│   ├── preload
│   │   └── index.ts
│   ├── renderer
│   │   └── index.ts
│   └── utils
│       ├── constants.ts
│       ├── hotkeys
│       │   └── index.js
│       └── logger
│           └── index.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
└── package.json
```

In `src/main/index.ts` I am trying to import the `src/utils/logger/index.ts` file by the `@utils/logger/index.ts` alias that is supposed to work, considering the `compilerOptions.paths` key in the `tsconfig.json` file; but instead I get the following error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@utils/logger/index' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Is this not the correct way to create aliases? If not how should I be doing it?

<sub>Also I am using esbuild, so if there's no solution with `tsconfig.json` an esbuild solution would be the best!</sub>

I have looked at all the solutions I could find about this on Google but none worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A definite problem is that you're missing the `/*` postfix in the paths map.

```
"paths": {
  "@utils/*": [
     "utils/*"
  ]
}
```

Everything else looks fine.

Comment: That fixed the issue in VSCode but now whenever I try building with esbuild the output tries to import using the alias too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with esbuild as of yet.
It seems that people have ran into the same problem in the past, and some have suggested using [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-ts-paths).
Also, could you post your package.json?

Comment: I am currently using the CLI for esbuild which as far as I can tell does not support plugins, I could move over to using the JS api though. Thanks for your help!